# Configuring generated keystore in jetty ssl file

Tags: ssl, jetty, jetty-9

I have to enable SSL in Jetty. I have generated keystore file using `Keytool`. I have included this keytool file in `JETTY_BASE\etc\myKeystore`. I have included `jetty-https.xml` and `jetty-ssl.xml` in `JETTY_BASE\etc`

jetty-https.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">
   <Call id="httpsConnector" name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
      <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector">
        <Arg name="server"><Ref refid="Server" /></Arg>
        <Arg name="acceptors" type="int"><Property name="ssl.acceptors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="selectors" type="int"><Property name="ssl.selectors" default="-1"/></Arg>
        <Arg name="factories">
          <Array type="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ConnectionFactory">
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SslConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="next">http/1.1</Arg>
                <Arg name="sslContextFactory"><Ref refid="sslContextFactory"/></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
            <Item>
              <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnectionFactory">
                <Arg name="config"><Ref refid="sslHttpConfig"/></Arg>
              </New>
            </Item>
          </Array>
        </Arg>
        <Set name="host"><Property name="jetty.host" /></Set>
        <Set name="port"><Property name="https.port" default="443" /></Set>
        <Set name="idleTimeout"><Property name="https.timeout" default="30000"/></Set>
        <Set name="soLingerTime"><Property name="jetty.https.soLingerTime" default="-1"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptorPriorityDelta"><Property name="jetty.https.acceptorPriorityDelta" default="0"/></Set>
        <Set name="acceptQueueSize"><Property name="jetty.https.acceptQueueSize" default="0"/></Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Configure>
```

jetty-ssl.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Configure id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
  <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.base" default="." />/<Property name="jetty.keystore" default=""/>etc/myKeystore</Set>
  <Set name="KeyStorePassword"><Property name="jetty.keystore.password" default=""/>password</Set>
  <Set name="KeyManagerPassword"><Property name="jetty.keymanager.password" default=""/>password</Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePath"><Property name="jetty.base" default="." />/<Property name="jetty.truststore" default=""/>etc/myKeystore</Set>
  <Set name="TrustStorePassword"><Property name="jetty.truststore.password" default=""/>password</Set>
  <Set name="EndpointIdentificationAlgorithm"></Set>
  <Set name="NeedClientAuth"><Property name="jetty.ssl.needClientAuth" default="false"/></Set>
  <Set name="WantClientAuth"><Property name="jetty.ssl.wantClientAuth" default="false"/></Set>
  <Set name="ExcludeCipherSuites">
    <Array type="String">
      <Item>SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5</Item>
      <Item>SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
      <Item>SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA</Item>
    </Array>
  </Set>
  <New id="sslHttpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
    <Arg><Ref refid="httpConfig"/></Arg>
    <Call name="addCustomizer">
      <Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.SecureRequestCustomizer"/></Arg>
    </Call>
  </New>
</Configure>
```

Though I have specified my keystore file as

```
  <Set name="KeyStorePath"><Property name="jetty.base" default="." />/<Property name="jetty.keystore" default=""/>etc/myKeystore</Set>
```

it is not recognized. Jetty uses default 'keystore' file located in 'JETTY_BASE/etc'. How to use the generated keystore file?

Answer (score 1):

Include the details in `start.ini` and delete the files `jetty-https.xml` and `jetty-ssl.xml`.

sample `start.ini`:

```
## Keystore file path (relative to $jetty.base)
jetty.sslContext.keyStorePath=etc/myKeystore

## Truststore file path (relative to $jetty.base)
jetty.sslContext.trustStorePath=etc/myKeystore

## Keystore password
jetty.sslContext.keyStorePassword=password

## Keystore type and provider
# jetty.sslContext.keyStoreType=JKS
# jetty.sslContext.keyStoreProvider=

## KeyManager password
jetty.sslContext.keyManagerPassword=password    
## Truststore password
jetty.sslContext.trustStorePassword=password
```

From Jetty [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/startup-modules.html):

> It is not recommended to use both a ${jetty.base}/start.ini file and a
> ${jetty.base}/start.d directory at the same time and doing so can
> cause issues.